# mdadm does not persist RAID when re-booting

Tags: mdadm, software-raid

I have created a RAID-0 with the following command:

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_750_EVO_500GB_ABC /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_750_EVO_500GB_XYZ
mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/md0
mount /dev/md0 /data1
```

However I find I have to re-run the mdadm command every time I boot the system. I have tried mdadm.conf but it does not help:

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

**Edit**: Answers to comments.

#1 I have no extra entries at /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 on fairly default settings, so the boot image's FS is ext4 if that is what you mean.

#2 Only RAID related entries on dmesg were stuff  like "raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm". I am not quite sure what to look for, "mdadm" is not found from the output.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
unused devices: <none>
```

#3 I haven't tried using partitions, I have done it this way since I intend to use the entire disk for this purpose. Originally I did it the same way with ZFS but for some reason got very poor performance so I'm using mdadm now. This shouldn't be related to the motherboard since I'm using software RAID?

As a side note, luckily the data is preserved when I re-create the RAID. But naturally it will get a new UUID, different from the one I previously stored to mdadm.conf. One hack could be to add the creation statement to root's cron but it seems like a dangerous hack.

**Edit 2**: Ooh both the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04) and /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf mention the update-initramfs but somehow I overlooked that. However after running it and having this at /etc/fstab it still didn't mount automatically:

```
/dev/md0 /data1 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 2
```

I also found /etc/modprobe.d/mdadm.conf, it only has the row "options md_mod start_ro=1". I hope mdadm reads both of these files. The added line at /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf is like this:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=myname:0 UUID=3fc...
```

After a reboot I didn't spot anything interesting on dmesg. Other outputs before I re-created the array:

```
$ sudo mdadm -Q /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_750_EVO_500GB_ABC
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_750_EVO_500GB_ABC: is not an md array

$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_750_EVO_500GB_ABC
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_750_EVO_500GB_ABC:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :    976773167 sectors at            1 (type ee)

$ sudo mdadm --assemble --verbose /dev/md0 2>&1 | grep -v /loop
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdd3 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd3
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdd2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000401)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd2
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdd1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdd (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdc9 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc9
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdc1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00008101)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdc (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdb (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 000004ea)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sda9 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda9
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sda1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00008101)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sda (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
```

Based on the output of lsblk the correct drives are /dev/sda and /dev/sdc. Oddly it shows two partitions, sda9 is 8 MB and sda1 is the rest of the drive. This is true also for /dev/sdc.

Comment: Please check you don't have duplicate or irrelevant entries in `mdadm.conf`. Do you have an initramfs boot image? If so you'll need to rebuild it

Comment: You are appending, please cat the content of the /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, also search for dmesg to see what's doing mdadm in the starting. Also `cat /proc/mdstat` after a reboot to see the mdadm service status after a fresh boot

Comment: also as i know some motherboards  will dismiss your raid after a reboot. have you tried to use partitions instead of a raw disk ?

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` (?)

Comment: @RedaSalih with Software RAID the motherboard knows nothing about it

Comment: I wanted to say the kernel :)

Comment: `--assemble` manually works? `--examine` works? Otherwise something is wiping your mdadm headers (partitions are mandatory). For `mdadm.conf`, `--detail --scan` tends to be too verbose, edit it to just have `ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=xyz` and nothing else (don't restrict devices or partition or host names). `mdadm.conf` can exist in multiple locations (`/etc`, `/etc/mdadm/`, `/etc/mdadm.conf.d/`, ...) make sure there is only one so as to not inadvertently use the wrong file. Update initramfs and make sure the bootloader actually uses the updated file.